# Is the master view controller not pushed in the nav stack when assigned to rootViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

I'm trying to hide the toolbar in the mast view controller of my `navigationViewControleler` hierarchy.

I create a new ViewController to be the `RootViewController` and set its `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` to YES.

But it seems that the very first time the app is launched this view controller does not respond to this because the toolbar is not hidden. (maybe on init this view is not pushed to the nav stack). Later, when coming from detail controller the toolbar is hidden.

In the app Delegate I do:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    AEMMasterViewController *masterViewController = [[[AEMMasterViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"AEMMasterViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
    masterViewController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;

    //Inicializar lista de eventos
    AEMEventosList *aux = [[AEMEventosList alloc] init];
    aux.delegate = masterViewController;

    //Asignar la lista de eventos a la variable miembro de la clase
    self.eventosList = aux;
    [aux release];

    // Comenzar la descarga de eventos desde el servidor
    [self.eventosList downloadEventos];

    self.navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:masterViewController] autorelease];
    //Configurar el toolbar
    self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;

   self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

The first time the app is loaded the toolbar is not hidden in the master view. After going to detail view and coming back (so the controller is pushed onto the nab stack) the toolbar is hidden.

How can I set the toolbar for the master view to be hidden on startup?
Is this master view controller not pushed on the nav stack the first time the view is loaded and this is why it does not respond to `hidesBottonBarWhenPushed`?

Answer (score 1):

```
self.navigationController.toolbarHidden = NO;
```

You're forcing the toolbar to be visible here. Setting `hidden` to `NO`. On your initial start up, this should be `YES` if you want to hide the toolbar. Or try removing this line altogether, and see if it honours the hidesBottomBar setting - at the moment you would be overriding it.

Comment: It should be straightforward but I have tried many settings and cannot get to understand how `toolbarHidden` and `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` they work together. In the end I just set `self.navigationController.toolbarHiden`property on `viewWillApper` in my viewControllers to whatever value I want.